# Checking valid inputs

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python, and I'm trying to make a program as part of a project. I'm trying to get the program to validate a users input seeing if it is one of the dictionary keys.

```
# dictionary linking month number to month name
months = {1: 'Jan', 2: 'Feb', 3: 'Mar', 4: 'Apr', 5: 'May', 6: 'Jun',
          7: 'Jul', 8: 'Aug', 9: 'Sep', 10:'Oct', 11: 'Nov', 12: 'Dec'}
# print out all the numbers and names
for num, name in months.items():
    print (str(num) + ": " + name)
monthChosen = input("Enter the number of a month (1-12)")
valid = False
while not valid:
    # make sure the user has chosen one of the correct numbers
    if monthChosen in months.keys():
        valid = True
    else:
        monthChosen = input("Make sure you enter a number (1-12)")
# return the number (int) of the month chosen
return int(monthChosen)
```

However, sometimes when I enter a valid number it works, and other times it doesn't.

EDIT: I'm using Python 3

Comment: replace input() with int(input())

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? They differ in the syntax of `print` and the result of `input()`.

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using python 3.

Input takes a "string" inputted by the user, a "string" - Your dictionary keys are "ints" So just add int() to the beginning of each input call to fix it.

```
# dictionary linking month number to month name
months = {1: 'Jan', 2: 'Feb', 3: 'Mar', 4: 'Apr', 5: 'May', 6: 'Jun',
          7: 'Jul', 8: 'Aug', 9: 'Sep', 10:'Oct', 11: 'Nov', 12: 'Dec'}
# print out all the numbers and names
for num, name in months.items():
    print (str(num) + ": " + name)
monthChosen = int(input("Enter the number of a month (1-12)"))
valid = False
while not valid:
    # make sure the user has chosen one of the correct numbers
    if monthChosen in months.keys():
        valid = True
    else:
        monthChosen = int(input("Make sure you enter a number (1-12)"))
# return the number (int) of the month chosen
return int(monthChosen)
```

Comment: This works for the first time, but if I input a number not in the range (1-12) and then when it tells me to try again, it does't work when I enter a valid number.

Answer (score 1):

you can use try block, like this:

```
try:
    if int(monthChosen) in range(1,13):   #OR  if int(monthChosen) in month.keys()
        # do your stuff
except:
     # show warning
```

Comment: You might want to add why you're using a try-except block, which is because int() raises an exception if it tries to converts any non-numeric string

Comment: Ok, so in a range, the first term is inclusive and he last is exclusive?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completed code sample that will help you out. You could use range(1,13), but if you want to replicate this same code for another use, months.items() works better. Also, "if not in" eliminates the need for a while loop in a more efficient way.

```
# dictionary linking month number to month name
months = {1: 'Jan', 2: 'Feb', 3: 'Mar', 4: 'Apr', 5: 'May', 6: 'Jun',
          7: 'Jul', 8: 'Aug', 9: 'Sep', 10:'Oct', 11: 'Nov', 12: 'Dec'}
# print out all the numbers and names
for num, name in months.items():
    print (str(num) + ": " + name)

monthChosen = input("Enter the number of a month (1-12)")

if monthChosen not in months.keys():
    monthChosen = input("Make sure you enter a number (1-12)")
    if monthChosen not in months.keys():
        print "You failed to properly enter a number from (1-12)"
    else:
        print int(monthChosen)
else:
    print int(monthChosen)
```